# Vis Graph Library, responsive design issue with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been recently having issues with the [Vis Library](http://visjs.org/) when it comes to responsive design within Twitter bootstrap. I have placed everything within a container (fixed width) but the graph itself needs to be within a pull page spread. What ways would people recommend to fully expand the element in page width but while keeping the element within the container tag.

The reasoning for keeping it within the container tag as it is built using Laravel Blade templates, and the container element is stored in a 'layout' view. I can't figure out a way to do this with CSS, would it have to be some maths on JavaScript side (Height & Width) which I'll have to apply to element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Graph2d, you can just give it a with of `'100%'`.

If you mean the Network, you can set width to `'100%'` too. On window resize, you have to call `network.redraw()` to enforce it to redraw itself with the new size.

Comment: Would that not stay within the size of `.container` of Twitter Bootstrap? As opposed to the page width.

Comment: Yes, it takes 100% of the parent element, so you have to style the parent element as desired. If you want the Timeline to take 100% of the page width, you will have to style the Timelines parent element such that it has 100% page width.